# k largest elements of GSL vector

Tags: c, sorting, gsl

I am trying to get the indices of the k largest elements in a `GSL` vector `v` of length > k.

The code goes as follows:

```
uint8_t Indices[k];
gsl_sort_vector_largest_index(Indices, k, v);
```

But, for some reason, only the first entry of `Indices` gets filled.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT :** That's a self-contained example as requested:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sort_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

uint8_t k = 3;
gsl_vector * v;
v = gsl_vector_alloc(10);
gsl_vector_set_all(v,.1);
gsl_vector_set(v, 7, .5); gsl_vector_set(v, 2, .3); gsl_vector_set(v, 4, .2);

uint8_t Indices[k];
gsl_sort_vector_largest_index(Indices, k, v);
for(uint8_t i=0;i<k;i++)
    printf("%u\n",Indices[i]);

gsl_vector_free(v);
}
```

This gives `7       0       0` as output while I was expecting `7       2       4`

Comment: Could you create a self-contained example? I.e., wrap it in a main function and initialize v with a set of values.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. Check any warnings you get. For example, `uint_8` may work, but according to the documentation, `gsl_sort_vector_largest_index` takes a `size_t`. And indeed, if I use that instead, I get your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Selecting-the-k-smallest-or-largest-elements.html#Selecting-the-k-smallest-or-largest-elements), `gsl_sort_vector_largest_index` takes a `size_t *` as its first argument, not `uint_8 *`.

Change your code to use `size_t` instead of `uint_8` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! :)